# Merging specific files in TortoiseSVN / branch practices

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a personal branch in which I work on multiple features concurrently.  Having completed a feature, I'd like to merge relevant files back into trunk, and I can't work out how.  Merge will unilaterally merge everything, and if I want any kind of granularity I have to go through the interface flow one file at a time.

I tried using the revision graph to compare branch and trunk, letting me select relevant files from the changes - but creating a patch from the unified differences doesn't include any new files.

"Merge range of revisions" isn't terribly useful either as many of my commits to my personal branch incorporate work on different features, as I work from multiple machines and have to make sure everything I do is committed, complete or not.

Am I just doing it wrong?  Should I be taking out a new branch for every single feature?  I feel like I'd have a dozen and a nightmare of a time building them all.  Should I be micromanaging my branch commits to make sure every feature is separated for later selection?  I can't muster a huge objection to that, I suppose, I'm just confused by the lack of what seems like the obvious capability to merge specific files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I just doing it wrong?

If "it" is your "branching policy", then - YES

If "it" is your "branch development policy", then - YES

> Should I be taking out a new branch for every single feature?

Maybe, but "it depends" from at least: amount of parallel branches, lifetime of every such branch, your merge habits (cumulative merges during development or "Big Bang" merges of finished features), thus - I can't give you **The Definitive Answer (tm)**

You can have less headache if you'll follow "branch per task" policy **OR** at least "commit per task" in shared branch. It will be at least *somehow manageable* for merges

Anyway, you have to read about [different merge-types](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html), pay attention to subtree and [cherrypick](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) merges:

- if you'll have commit per task in common branch, you can just collect all related to feature commits in branch and cherrypick these subsets separately into trunk
- with branch per task you'll use ordinary merges into trunk, but a lot of merge-hell with cross-branch merging (this is a real pain on long run)

Now you have only one way: mix of subtree and cherrypick with giant amount of handwork:

- collect list of files, related to feature
- collect list of revisions, related to feature
- subtree-merge every file from p.1 with cherrypicking revisions from p.2 at the same command (and anyway, you'll have more than single merge for every feature, because "Merge file N for feature X..." for *each independent part* of source tree is a must)